# Receive Webhook Data and then create a file in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, webhooks

I am trying to create a Nodejs app that will receive a webhook with order information and then store in Google Cloud Storage as an XML file. I haven't found any example of this, any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: On the official documentation you can find a Node.js example: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-nodejs

Comment: This is a loose comment ... but since Cloud Storage is itself a REST based service, in theory / principle ... you could direct your source REST callback directly to Google APIs to create the content of the object directly?     See for example:  https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-object-upload